# Abnormal consumption of RAM Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows, server, ram

I have a sac server turning on Windows Server 2008 R2.

I'm have abnormal consumption of RAM !! and i can't find the process that use the most of them !

I have found RAMMap. It's alos unable the find the process that use the 80/90 % of the RAM

Please Help me. I'let you show some screenshots below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/64Ty8.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/QybXF.png

Answer (score -2):

Do you have a SQL Server running? Try restart it and look for the RAM again.

Look also at this post : https://serverfault.com/questions/115982/weird-memory-usage-in-windows-server-2008-r2

Comment: Thanks for your replay. It have restated the SQL Server services.

Comment: How can I show the ram consumption of running Services ?